# how to hide/ show input box on radio button click event

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide and show input field on radio button click event my HTML is

```
<input type="radio" id="abc" name="abc1" checked = "checked" value="Experienced" />
<label> Experienced </label>  
<input type="radio" id="xyz" name="xyz1" checked = "checked"  value="Fresher" />
<label>Fresher</label>  
<input type="text"  name="cardno" id="tyx" /><br />
<p > Number</p>
```

What I want is when radio button with `value="Fresher"` is clicked the input box `name="cardno"` should be hidden.

I tried to solve this by using jQuery but it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name$='abc1']").click(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == 'Experianced') {
            $("#tyx").show();
        } else if (value == 'Fresher') {
            $("#tyx").hide();
        }
    });
```

Can any body help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

name of your radio button should be same to check on click event or make array name of your radio button

like below code

```
<input type="radio" id="abc" name="abc1" checked = "checked" value="Experienced" />
<label> Experienced </label>  
<input type="radio" id="xyz" name="abc1" checked = "checked"  value="Fresher" />
<label>Fresher</label>  
<input type="text"  name="cardno" id="tyx" /><br />
<p > Number</p>
```

and then create function like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input[name$='abc1']").click(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == 'Experianced') {
        $("#tyx").show();
    } else if (value == 'Fresher') {
        $("#tyx").hide();
    }
});
```

please reply if i can help you more..

Answer (score 0):

change the spelling to `Experienced`

you used

```
if (value == 'Experianced')
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the typo in **Experienced**, try setting up a click event for each radio button:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[name="abc1"][value="Experienced"]').click(function() {
     $("#tyx").show();
   });
   $('input[name="xyz1"][value="Fresher"]').click(function() {
     $("#tyx").hide();
   });
 });
```

**Note:**

You can simplify your selectors to use ids with:

```
$('#abc')
```

and

```
$('#xyz')
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input[type='radio']").click(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == 'Experianced') {
        $("#tyx").show();
    } else if (value == 'Fresher') {
        $("#tyx").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<input type="radio" id="abc" name="jobtype" checked = "checked" value="Experienced" />
<label> Experienced </label>  
<input type="radio" id="xyz" name="jobtype" checked = "checked"  value="Fresher" />
<label>Fresher</label>  
<input type="text"  name="cardno" id="tyx" /><br />
<p > Number</p>
```

Radio buttons of same group should have same `name`

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("input[name='jobtype']").click(function () {
      var value = this.value;
      if (value == 'Experienced') {
        $("#tyx").show();
      } 
     else{
        $("#tyx").hide();
      }
   });
});
```